# mypy: "__eq__" incompatible with supertype "object"

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

this is my code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def __eq__(self, other: 'Person') -> bool:
        return self.id == other.id

   def compare(self, other: 'Person') -> bool:
        return self.id == other.id
```

mypy throw `error: Argument 1 of "__eq__" incompatible with supertype "object"`.

But if I remove `__eq__` method, mypy won't complain it though `compare` is same as `__eq__`, what should I do?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2783)

Comment: I tried it and it works, I just wonder if using `Any` a good practice here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The root problem is that the `__eq__` method is supposed to accept any object: doing `my_object == 3` is legal at runtime, and should always return False. You can see this for yourself by checking the baseline type definition for `object` [in Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/builtins.pyi#L31): the signature of `__eq__` is given as `def __eq__(self, o: object) -> bool: ...`

So, in order to make this work, the correct way of implementing `__eq__` would be to do the following:

```
def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
    if not isinstance(other, Person):
        # If we return NotImplemented, Python will automatically try
        # running other.__eq__(self), in case 'other' knows what to do with
        # Person objects.
        return NotImplemented
    return self.id == other.id
```

And in fact, if you update the version of mypy you're using, it'll print out a note recommending you structure your code in this way.

However, the problem with this approach is that mypy will now no longer complain if you do something silly like `Person() == 3`. Technically, that ought to return a bool, but pragmatically, your code probably has a bug if you're comparing a person object against an int.

Thankfully, mypy very recently acquired a feature that can flag these sorts of errors: [`--strict-equality`](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/6370). Now, when you run mypy with that flag, doing `Person() == 3` will make mypy output errors like `Non-overlapping equality check (left operand type: "Person", right operand type: "int")` even if you define `__eq__` in the way described above.

Note that you'll need to use the latest version of mypy from master to use this flag until the next version of mypy (0.680) is released. That should happen in roughly 2 to 3 weeks as of time of writing.

---

If defining the `__eq__` in the manner described above is not something you can do for whatever reason, I would personally recommend suppressing the type error instead of replacing Person with `Any`.

So basically, do this:

```
def __eq__(self, other: 'Person') -> bool:  # type: ignore
    return self.id == other.id
```

...maybe along with an brief note of why you're suppressing the error.

The rationale here is that this definition of `__eq__` strictly speaking *is* unsafe (it violates something known as the Liskov substitution principle) -- and if you need to do something unsafe, it's probably better to explicitly mark that you're subverting the type system rather then hiding it by using Any.

And at least this way, you can still make expressions like `Person() == 3` be a type error -- if you use `Any`, expressions like `Person() == 3` will silently type-check. At that point, you might as well just use `object` and structure your code to behave correctly.

Comment: even with `--strict-equality` mypy is happy to compare `Path("foo") == "foo"` which returns False

Comment: Please, update your typeshed link. It should point to: https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/builtins.pyi