# mypy strict not detecting booleans, returning 'no-any-return'

Tags: mypy

For the following function

```
    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, Node):
            return False
        return other.address == self.address
```

mypy is reporting `error: Returning Any from function declared to return "bool"  [no-any-return]`
This seems strange, as it seems like both statements unambiguously return a boolean. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__eq__#object.__eq__) returns `Any`, not `bool`, as counter-intuitive as this sounds. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801832/mypy-eq-incompatible-with-supertype-object).

Comment: To add onto @MrBeanBremen's answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67798096/338710. It seems that this is done for operator overloading reasons.